# Spacing for the front wheel on GT Agressor

Tags: rims, size, wheels

I'm thinking about purchasing the NUKEPROOF HORIZON V2 FRONT WHEEL or Spank 359 vibrocore both 27.5. I'm just wondering the best wheelset for my bike and what would fit.  I had an accident and my rim got bent,  so I need a new wheelset.

I have a GT aggressor pro.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your front wheel probably has an Over Locknut Dimension of 100mm.  This has to match a new wheel's hub.  Measure that with a ruler in the front forks between the inside faces of the two dropouts.

You'll also need a wheel that has the same brake setup (disk caliper mount or a rim braking track)  If you have disk brakes, its likely the rotor can be transferred over, like your tyre/tube.

Your rim diameter has to be 27.5" to match the geometry of the frame, and should have about the same inner-width on the rim as the old one.  The valve hole should be the same as the old rim too, matching either a schrader or presta valve stem.

Which rim to choose is really off-topic.  If two things are the same, and you can only get one of them, then its not really a fair comparison.  And in these days of supply chain weirdness you may not have all the options you want.

---

Your other option is to attempt a straightening and re-true of your existing wheel.  That depends on how badly it was bent and your skill level at manual tasks.

Also, consider the root cause of the bending and how you can avoid it next time, by changing something about your riding.

Comment: Thank you so and whats funny is the rim bent from my bike rack detaching and my bike dangleing on the road:/.

Comment: @CadenSorensen sorry to hear that, but at least it didn't fall off and get run over!   Next time use more/better straps to secure bike to rack, or do without the car and ride the bike there.  Personally I like big Velcro straps because they hold well and can be reused, or old inner tubes.  I do not like rope for this purpose.